mongoose.Model.findOne always returning null
I have the following mongoose schema:
export interface MusicInput {
  title: string
  artist: string
  album: string
  genre: string
  userId?: string // maybe make this mongoose.type.ObjectId
}

export interface MusicDocument extends mongoose.Document, MusicInput {
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
}

const musicSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    artist: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    album: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    genre: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      require: false
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

const MusicModel = mongoose.model<MusicDocument>('Music', musicSchema)
export default MusicModel

What I want to do is search for a music based on the music._id. But I have tried everything possible: MusicModel.findOne({_id: <some_valid_id>}), or MusicModel.findById(<some_valid_id>) But it always returning null. Here is the code I am currently using to find a music by their id:
export const findMusic = async (
  query: FilterQuery<MusicDocument>,
  options: QueryOptions = { lean: true }
) => {
  return MusicModel.findOne(query, {}, options)
}

What is going on? I have been surfing the internet but still can not find the solution.
For Reference
Mongoose Version => 8.5.2

For people that have encountered such a problem, even though your problem might be unique, still sharing my answer will sure benefit you. My issue was when I was testing my application, I have added some dummy data, and when I entered the data I have included _id property and instead of being stored as an ObjectId they were stored as strings. Hope this helps.
